# Flutter Calling MethodChannel and EventChannel outside of MainActivity

Tags: android, flutter, dart, native

I searched a lot but failed to solve my problem. I want to send data from native Android to Flutter via **MethodChannel** or **EventChannel**. I wrote a class **NotificationGrabber** that **extends** **NotificationListenerService** in order to catch notifications on Android. Overriding the **onNotificationPosted** method I successfully catch incoming notifications. Now I'm trying to send these notifications to Flutter with **MethodChannel** or **EventChannel** but these constructors need a **BinaryMessenger**. I see from various tutorials that use **flutterView** as a BinaryMessenger (correct me if I am wrong). Because of **onNotificationsPosted** method isn't in MainActivity, how could I do that from my NotificationGrabber class? How can I use another correct BinaryMessenger? Thank you all!

```
public class NotificationGrabber extends NotificationListenerService {
    private static final String CHANNEL = "mynotifications/getnotifications";
    private String TAG = this .getClass().getSimpleName() ;

    @Override
    public void onNotificationPosted (StatusBarNotification sbn) {
        Log. d ( TAG , "onNotificationPosted" ) ;
        sendNotificationsToFlutter(sbn);

    }

    private void sendNotificationsToFlutter(StatusBarNotification sbn) {
        Gson tempGson = new Gson();

        String jsonNotifications = tempGson.toJson(sbn);

        MethodChannel channel = new MethodChannel( <What could I put here?>, CHANNEL);

        channel.invokeMethod("returnedNotification", jsonNotifications );

    }
    .
    .
    .
    .
}
```